# Get list of query/400 queries for given user in JT400

Tags: java, ibm-midrange, jt400, corretto

I am trying to get a list of all of my query/400 queries using the Java library "JT400".

Here is the list represented visually in our terminal application:

[image]

I am an accountant by trade, not an AS400 programmer, so I don't know where or how these queries are stored or how the data is retrieved to create the above terminal interface.

I have worked a little with "ObjectList" querying, but don't know which library they would be in (if any). I came across some IBM tool online [IBM Tool Doc](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/system/files/inline-files/$FILE/Query400%20Discovery_0.pdf), which is supposed to provide a command line interface for searching for query/400 objects, but I do not know if we have that installed or if it can do what I need.

Here is my code so far:

```
ObjectList queryList = new ObjectList(as400, ObjectList.CURRENT_LIBRARY, ObjectList.ALL, ObjectList.ALL);
        try {
            // Retrieve the list of queries:
            queryList.load();

            try {
                System.out.println(queryList.getLength());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Enumeration queries = queryList.getObjects();

            for (Enumeration e = queries; e.hasMoreElements();{
                System.out.println(e.nextElement());
            }

        } catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println("There was an exception processing the list of queries:");
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I finally got this to run without error, but the objects it returns don't look familiar to me and certainly are not the list of query names that I am used to seeing in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question.

You can generate a list of query/400 queries by user by using the ObjectList class in JT400.

**The key is to use "*QRYDFN" in your constructor when defining the object type**. In my code, I also specified the specific user in the first string parameter. See constructor info and my code below:

**JT400 Docs "ObjectList":**

[image: JT400 "ObjectList" docs]

**Working code:**

```
public static void ListQueries() throws AS400SecurityException, ObjectDoesNotExistException, IOException, InterruptedException, ErrorCompletingRequestException, RequestNotSupportedException {

    AS400 as400 = new AS400();

    // Define your object list parameters
    // vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    ObjectList queryList = new ObjectList(as400, as400.getUserId(), ObjectList.ALL, "*QRYDFN");
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    
    // Execute your search
    queryList.load();
    
    // Create an enumeration containing the returned objects
    Enumeration queries = queryList.getObjects(); 
    
    // Iterate through the objects to print the query names
    for (Enumeration e = queries; e.hasMoreElements();)
    {System.out.println(e.nextElement());}
}
```

**Resulting list:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think your problems are here
`new ObjectList(as400, ObjectList.CURRENT_LIBRARY, ObjectList.ALL, ObjectList.ALL);`

1. "CURRENT_LIBRARY" is likely different for the JT400 connection versus your 5250 session.  I'd specify the library shown in you 5250 screen.
2. The final "ObjectList.ALL" for the `objectType` parameter.  If all you're interested in is Query/400 queries use `"*QRYDFN"`